# django running server error while executing command in cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

please help me solve this problem when I execute "python manage.py runserver " I get this error. I have already activated the virtual environment

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\projects\AM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\projects\AM\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\projects\AM\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\projects\AM\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\projects\AM\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\projects\AM\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\projects\AM\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
RuntimeError: __class__ not set defining 'AbstractBaseUser' as <class 'django.contrib.auth.base_user.AbstractBaseUser'>. Was __classcell__ propagated to type.__new__?
```

and it's my setting.py file. I could run the server without any problem in the morning but I don't know what happened I get this error all the time.

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.13.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5+4(3^b$skyxymrc-(2%ag7-t)fuedd)e!5nwn!*u^%)0sy%@t'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: how does your `settings.py` look like?

Comment: thank you for your attention.  I add settings.py file to my main question

Comment: and my python version 3.8.5 I just updated it after this error

Comment: I was working with models in my project and it happend after that i tried other virtual enviroments and i get this error all the time iv updated python but didnt help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Django 1.9, which is very old and does not seems to be compatible with Python 3.8. The following article describing changes in [Python class constructing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) is resembling your error:

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython 3.6 and later, the **class** cell is passed to the metaclass as a **classcell** entry in the class namespace. If present, this must be propagated up to the type.**new** call in order for the class to be initialised correctly. Failing to do so will result in a RuntimeError in Python 3.8.

I'd recommend to upgrade the version of Django, which will be compatible with your Python version.

Comment: thank you very much. I really appreciate your attention. can you please help me a little more I don't know which version of Django to use and how to update the version. thank you very much again.

Comment: Lowest Django version supporting Python 3.8 is Django 2.2, so upgrade at least to that one. The more versions you'll be upgrading across, the more breaking changes you'll need to mitigate. You can check release notes for each minor version (1.10, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2) to see the breaking changes, but that can take a lot of time, so just upgrade and then deal with the errors you'll be getting by consulting the release notes. Or you can just start fresh with the latest Django, could be the quickest way if your app does not have too much in it yet. good luck.